# How to add user input to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, set

```
s = set()
i = 0
while True:
    user_input = input("enter words: ")
    for words in user_input.strip().split():
        words_from_list = words.strip().split()
        for x in words_from_list:
            s.add(x) 
    for i in s:
    print(i)
```

the code above should show output like below

enter text: how are you dear

how 1

are 2

you 3

dear 4

enter text: how was your morning

how 1

your 5

was 6

morning 7

dear 4

random sequence is due to set the repeated element should have same sequence number

Comment: Please do not provide "the desired output" as an example, but rather than an explanation. Do you want to print out all words found with their index found in the sentence?

Comment: 0x6d64 actually what i have to do is add the user input to a set and then to a dict, those elements in set should come in each like each word and then in dict it keys should be words and number should be values like above shown, how do i do this

Comment: You don't tell us what the numbers mean. Are they the order of insertion? If yes, then let's not use a set but a dict. In this dict we use the word as a key, and the value would be the sequence number.

Comment: @0x6d64 these numbers are values in a dict in front each word which represents keys for the value is length of that particular input from the user like if someone types how are you (how will be key against value 1) (are will be key against value 2) (you will be key against value 3) i hope you understand what i mean to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you wanted to do this:

```py
s = set()
i = 0
while True:
    user_input = input("enter words: ")
    for words in user_input.strip().split():
        words_from_list = words.strip().split()
        for x in words_from_list:
            s.add(x)
    for i in s:
        print(i)
```

Comment: thank you for your support half of the problem solved one more thing please now the output should come with numbers using dictionary like the one above i have updated the output again can you please check and reply.